# .load function to call specific Class

Tags: jquery, class, load

I am trying to get Latest News section of couple of news websites in one page. 
I have found out about .load function in JQuery has the ability. But how?

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>$("#today").load(http://www.today.mn + '.lastnews-wrapper'), function(data){};</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="today" style="width:400px; height:700px border:1px solid; border:#FF2;"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

so far this is what i did. but the screen is still blank

Comment: .load() loads stuff from the server not the internet. I think what you are after is Ajax and reloading if new data is available.

Comment: a syntax error: you must wrap the url in quotes and remove the `, function(data){}` part... A conceptual error: you will fail to load the content most likely due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors (load() syntax, css, url, load callback etc), and probably origin restriction.

Try this - assuming that the container: `.lastnews-wrapper` actually holds the data you are after.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){ 
            $("#today").load("http://www.today.mn .lastnews-wrapper",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
               if(statusTxt=="success")
                   console.log("Loaded successfully!");
               if(statusTxt=="error")
                   console.log("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="today" style="width:400px; height:700px; border:1px solid #FF2;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at the console you should see a failure (or success) message with the cause.

Enjoy.